# Transform array into object with array values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to transform this array

```
[ { _id: 'indoor', count: 12 }, { _id: 'outdoor', count: 34 } ]
```

into this result:

```
{ label: ['in', 'out'], data: [12, 34]}
```

So I need to get the labels (`_id`) in an array and replace them with some individual text and I need to get the values as data array.
The order of both should be the same of course.

For the second part I would do something like

```
array.map(c => c.count)
```

I can do the same thing with the label value, but how do I use individual text?
E.g. 'indoor' should be replaced by 'car' and 'outdoor' should replaced by 'plane'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method:

```js
let sourceData = [
    { _id: 'indoor', count: 12 },
    { _id: 'outdoor', count: 34 }
];

const maps = {indoor: 'in', outdoor: 'out'};    

const result = sourceData.reduce((a, c) => {
    a.label = a.label || [];
    a.data = a.data || [];

    a.label.push(maps[c._id]);
    a.data.push(c.count);

    return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

You can sort your desired array in custom order:

```js
let sourceData = [
    { _id: 'indoor', count: 12 },
    { _id: 'outdoor', count: 34 }
];

const maps = {indoor: 'in', outdoor: 'out'};    

const result = sourceData.reduce((a, c) => {
    a.label = a.label || [];
    a.data = a.data || [];

    a.label.push(maps[c._id]);
    a.data.push(c.count);

    return a;
}, {});

result.label.sort((a, b) => {
  const order = {'out': 1, 'in': 2, undefined: 3};
  return order[a] - order[b];
});

console.log(`custom order of labels: `, result);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to change the order of the data by a given label order? For example if I want to get the 'out' value at first position and of course there are more data values...

Comment: @user3142695  yeah, it is possible

Comment: But not with the reduce function as it is used in your answer, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let labels = {
  indoor: 'car',
  outdoor: 'plaine'
};

let input = [{
  _id: 'indoor',
  count: 12
}, {
  _id: 'outdoor',
  count: 34
}];
let output = input.reduce((output, inObj) => {
  output.label.push(labels[inObj._id]);
  output.data.push(inObj.count);
  return output;
}, {
  label: [],
  data: []
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = 
[ 
  { _id: 'indoor', count: 12 }, 
  { _id: 'outdoor', count: 34 } 
]
const result = {
  label: data.map(a => a._id.replace('door','')),
  data: data.map(e => e.count)
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the map call back you can check the text and return the required string

```js
let data = [{
  _id: 'indoor',
  count: 12
}, {
  _id: 'outdoor',
  count: 34
}]

let newData = {
  label: data.map((item) => {
    if (item._id === 'indoor') {
      return 'in';
    } else {
      return 'out';
    }

  }),
  data: data.map(item => item.count)

};
console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [ { _id: 'indoor', count: 12 }, { _id: 'outdoor', count: 34 } ];   
arr.map(o => [o._id === 'indoor' ? 'in' : 'out', o.count])
    .reduce((p, c) => ({
        label: [...p.label, c[0]]),
        data: [...p.data, c[1]])
    }), {
        label: [],
        data: []
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [ { _id: 'indoor', count: 12 }, { _id: 'outdoor', count: 34 } ];

const indoor = data.filter((item) => item._id === 'indoor').map((i) => i.count);
const outdoor = data.filter((item) => item._id === 'outdoor').map((i) => i.count);

const res = { label: ['in', 'out'], data: [...indoor, ...outdoor]};

console.log(res);
```

Will give you next:

```
{
  label: [
    "in",
    "out"
  ],
  data: [
    12,
    34
  ]
}
```